# plotly graph object colors to similar

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I try to plot values using plotly graph objects, and use one column to set the color.

```
fig_1.add_trace(
    go.Scattermapbox(
            lat=data.latitude, 
            lon=data.longitude,
            marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(size=9, color=data.id_nr),   
            )
        )
```

However, the values are very high numbers (id numbers, int64) and thereby, id numbers which are closer to each other (100k different rather than 1M) will appear almost as the same color.

**Is there a way to set the colours as discrete colours?** using

```
... color=data.id_nr.astype(str)
```

as used in Plotly express to make the coolers discrete does not work.

> Invalid element(s) received for the 'color' property of
> scattermapbox.marker

The basic question is: **Can you set the colors that each value, however how close or distanced the delta is, gets a unique color?**

---

**EDIT:**
The id values are more like:

```
id=[1,2,5,100004,100007,100009]
```

In combination with continuous coloring by plotly, the first three and the last three are kind of identically in color.
Plotly express solves this with changing the int values (of id) to strings, making them discrete.

---

**EDIT2 :**

A solution would be to separate the data by ID Then add a trace for each ID. However, this is not ..."sexy" and I would rather know a solution with plotly handling the colors discretely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recreated the data and created the code by adapting the example from the [official reference](https://plotly.com/python/scattermapbox/#multiple-markers) to your assignment. The format of the data is a data frame with three columns: id column, latitude and longitude, and location name. In the definition of the marker, I used the id column to define the color, and specified 'Viridis' as the color scale, which is a continuous color map. See this for a concrete [example](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#color-scale-for-scatter-plots-with-graph-objects) of introducing a color scale in a scatter plot.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

lat = [38.91427,38.91538,38.91458,38.92239,38.93222,38.90842,38.91931,38.93260,38.91368,38.88516,38.921894,38.93206, 38.91275]
lon = [-77.02827,-77.02013,-77.03155,-77.04227,-77.02854,-77.02419,-77.02518,-77.03304,-77.04509,-76.99656,-77.042438,-77.02821,-77.01239]
name = ["The coffee bar","Bistro Bohem","Black Cat", "Snap","Columbia Heights Coffee","Azi's Cafe", "Blind Dog Cafe","Le Caprice","Filter","Peregrine","Tryst","The Coupe","Big Bear Cafe"]
ids =  [1,2,3,4,5001,5002,5003,5004,100004,100007,100009,100010,100011]
colors = px.colors.qualitative.Alphabet[:len(lat)]

df = pd.DataFrame({'id':ids, 'lat':lat,'lon':lon,'name':name,'colors': colors})

df.head()
    id  lat     lon     name    colors
0   1   38.91427    -77.02827   The coffee bar  #AA0DFE
1   2   38.91538    -77.02013   Bistro Bohem    #3283FE
2   3   38.91458    -77.03155   Black Cat   #85660D
3   4   38.92239    -77.04227   Snap    #782AB6
4   5001    38.93222    -77.02854   Columbia Heights Coffee     #565656

import plotly.graph_objects as go

mapbox_access_token = open("mapbox_api_key.txt").read()

fig = go.Figure(go.Scattermapbox(
        lat=df['lat'],
        lon=df['lon'],
        mode='markers',
        marker=go.scattermapbox.Marker(
            size=16,
            color=df['colors'],
            #colorscale='Viridis'
        ),
        text=df['name'],
    ))

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1000,
    height=500,
    hovermode='closest',
    mapbox=dict(
        accesstoken=mapbox_access_token,
        bearing=0,
        center=dict(
            lat=38.92,
            lon=-77.07
        ),
        pitch=0,
        zoom=11
    ),
)

fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the indepth code. Next time I should provide a working example. However, the problem is, that the id values are more like: [1,2,3,100000,100002,100003]. This results in plotly thinking that the first three and the second three are belonging together, or better said, it uses continues coloring which ends up with the first three and the last three in a very similar color range. Changing the colorscale does not change it. in ploty express this is solved by discretisizing the colors by turning int to string. But this is not possible here.

Comment: I wish there had been an explanation of the id example from the beginning, but I think you can draw the intended graph by creating a column with this id given an arbitrary color and defining it in color.

Comment: The commented content is now reflected in the code and graphs. The color scale was made to match the number of colors in the data using qualitative colors. How many unique numbers of ids do you have in your data? Visualization by color has its limitations, so it is common to use color to distinguish between groupings.

Comment: Sorry for the late edit of the ids. Thank you a lot for your updated version. This does the dead. 
I used a random color generator which kind of works,... but random :-) so sometimes I hit nice color separation, sometimes not. Yours is much better.Cheers